# How can I clone the entire git repo

Tags: git, github

I am going to clone a Android repo on github, however, one of the folder, `volley`, cannot be cloned, it always empty.
[image]

I think the `volley` is from https://github.com/google/volley, so how can I download the entire repo. I have tried to use `git clone --recursive`, but it said `fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'SimpleZhihuDaily/volley'`

Comment: You need to run git submodule init and git submodule update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did clone the entire repository. The `volley` folder is a git submodule which points at another repository. Normally, `--recursive` tells git to fetch all submodules (and the submodules of those submodules) when you clone the repository. However, the error message suggests there's a problem with the submodule repository. It looks like the repository [no longer exists](https://github.com/SimpleZhihuDaily/volley).

If this is indeed the Google volley repository you think it is, try cloning the repository without `--recursive`. Then edit the `.gitmodules` and change the path of the volley entry to `https://github.com/google/volley.git`. Then run

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

If the Google repository contains the same commit that the repository was pointing at, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but I cannot find any file named `.gitmodules`, does that mean I need to create a new file named `.gitmodules`?

Comment: Yeah, based on the error message it sounds like the repository got corrupted. Can you add a link to the repository in your question?

Comment: Yes, I still cannot figure it out, I cannot find where the git defines the address of `volley`.
[Link](https://github.com/Jameeeees/Simplified-Zhihu-Daily)